# To prove $a^2+ab+b^2 \Big|(a+b)^{2n}+a^{2n}+b^{2n}$ whenever $3$ does not divide $n$

Tags: number-theory

If $3$ does not divide a positive integer $n$ , then how to prove that $a^2+ab+b^2 \Big|(a+b)^{2n}+a^{2n}+b^{2n}$ ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** This question is equivalent to  considering

$$ x^2 + x + 1 \mid (x+1) ^{2n} + x^{2n} + 1 $$

**Hint:** Use the cube roots of unity. Specifically, $ \omega^2 + \omega + 1 = 0$.

Show that $ ( \omega +1)^{2n} + \omega^{2n} + 1^{2n} = 0 \Leftrightarrow 3 \not \mid n$.

Answer (score 2):

note $a^2+ab+b^2=(a-b\omega)(a-b\omega^2)$. Show that $a=b\omega$ and $a=b\omega^2$ are roots to the expression $(a+b)^{2n}+a^{2n}+b^{2n}$ as well. In dojng that you will need $3 \not| n$.

Answer (score 1):

I will stay in the reals. Note that:
$$(a+b)^2\equiv ab \mod{a^2+ab+b^2}\implies (a+b)^{2n}\equiv (ab)^n \mod{a^2+ab+b^2}$$
So $(a+b)^n+a^{2n}+b^{2n}\equiv a^nb^n+a^{2n}+b^{2n}$. Also, we know that $a^3\equiv b^3$. So setting $n=3q+1$, we have:
$$a^nb^n+a^{2n}+b^{2n}\equiv ab^{6q+1}+a^2b^{6q}+b^{6q+2} \equiv b^{6q}(ab+a^2+b^2)\equiv 0$$
Similarly, if $n=3q+2$:
$$a^nb^n+a^{2n}+b^{2n}\equiv a^2b^{6q+2}+ab^{6q+3}+b^{6q+4} \equiv b^{6q+2}(a^2+ab+b^2)\equiv 0$$